# Error 'Unknown symbol __copy_to_user' during module load

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64

I have NAS `Terramaster F4-210` based on arm64 Realtek RTD1296 CPU. It has custom `OpenWrt 15.05.1` based firmware with 4.4.18 linux kernel. I want to create kernel module to use my zigbee stick (cdc-acm - USB Modem (CDC ACM) support) and run homeassistant on it.

```
# uname -a
Linux TNAS-BA68 4.4.18-g8bcbd8a-dirty #1327 SMP Mon Aug 31 11:55:52 CST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded appropriate [kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/?h=v4.4.18), created some config and after installing my newly compiled module I get the following errors in kernel log:

```
# modprobe cdc-acm
1 module could not be probed
- cdc-acm

# dmesg
...
cdc_acm: Unknown symbol __copy_to_user (err 0)
cdc_acm: Unknown symbol __copy_from_user (err 0)
cdc_acm: Unknown symbol _mcount (err 0)
```

As far as I understand that means module expects `copy_to_user`, `copy_from_user`, `mcount` to be part of the kernel (or other loaded module). But kernel doesn't export these symbols:

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep copy_to_user
ffffff80082923f0 T copy_to_user_page
ffffff80087d2600 T __arch_copy_to_user
ffffff80087e67b0 t kfifo_copy_to_user
ffffff8008871854 T my_copy_to_user
```

File [arch/arm64/include/asm/uaccess.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/include/asm/uaccess.h?h=v4.4.18#n264) has definition of copy_to_user:

```
extern unsigned long __must_check __copy_to_user(void __user *to, const void *from, unsigned long n);
...
static inline unsigned long __must_check copy_to_user(void __user *to, const void *from, unsigned long n)
```

File [arch/arm64/lib/copy_to_user.S](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/lib/copy_to_user.S?h=v4.4.18#n68) contains source code of __copy_to_user:

```
ENTRY(__copy_to_user)
ALTERNATIVE("nop", __stringify(SET_PSTATE_PAN(0)), ARM64_HAS_PAN, CONFIG_ARM64_PAN)
...
ENDPROC(__copy_to_user)
```

My initial idea was I have bad kernel configuration or bad toolchain. So I used toolchain and OpenWrt+kernel configuration from [banana pi W2](https://github.com/BPI-SINOVOIP/BPI-W2-bsp) board which has the same CPU. Without any luck but compile warning had disappeared.

So can somebody please confirm that the problem can't be solved by applying some different kernel configuration or proper toolchain. Instead kernel source code must be modified. E.g. instead of `__copy_to_user` one of `__arch_copy_to_user` or `my_copy_to_user` must be used.

So my assumption is: Terramaster took kernel sources, modified (probably used __arch_copy_to_user instead of __copy_to_user) and then compiled sources.

BTW: I also checked kernel sources and didn't find `__arch_copy_to_user`. Does that mean it was introduced by kernel sources modifications or it still can be present thereby usage of some nasty defs.

Comment: "My initial idea was I have bad kernel configuration or bad toolchain." - Yes, it seems like that. "Unknown symbol" errors with such "base" functions normally signal that your module is compiled against a kernel, which doesn't correspond to the running kernel.

Comment: Ok. It seems function `__copy_from_user` -> `__arch_copy_from_user` was renamed in kernel 4.8. That means kernel was built with wrong version and in fact kernel version is more close to 4.9

Comment: But on the other hand kernel 4.8 has cdc_parse_cdc_header function in usb core while Terramaster kernel doesn't have it. So probably they use some custom kernel with backports.